# Данные из двух базы данных в одном запросе

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Есть 2 БД `db1` и `db2`. В них есть таблицы с одинаковой структурой.

```
db1.table1
----------
id
name
date


db2.table2
----------
id
name
date
```

Есть запрос

```
select t1.name 
  from db1.table1 as t1, db2.table2 as t2
    where t1.name = t2.name
```

В `mysql` базах запрос получается, но в `posgresql` базе не могу сделать, пишет ошибку.

Можно ли такой запрос сделать на `postgresql`

Comment: *в `posgresql` базе не могу сделать, пишет ошибку* Документация утверждает, что в `postgresql` всё так же, как и в `mysql`. Покажите запрос и сообщение об ошибке. Полностью, текстом, копипастом. Ещё - попробуйте обойтись без алиасов, но ВЕЗДЕ указывать не только таблицу, но и схему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если под БД подразумеваются именно разные `database`, а не `schema` - то:

> cross-database references are not implemented

В `postgresql` не реализованы обращения между разными базами данных одного кластера.

Что, впрочем, не значит, что вообще нельзя так сделать. На выбор доступны расширение [`dblink`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) и механизм [`foreign data wrapper`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html).

- `dblink` позволяет написать и выполнить любой запрос к другому `postgresql` серверу (или этому же самому)
- `foreign data wrapper` часть стандарта `SQL/MED`, позволяет описать внешний источник данных - не обязательно `postgresql`, но `postgres_fdw` есть в стандартной поставке, тогда как другие необходимо ставить отдельно. И затем обращаться к этим внешним данным из запросов будто они обычные локальные таблицы.

Оба способа могут обращаться к внешним `postgresql`, и, соответственно, ничто не мешает ходить в тот же самый `postgresql` локально, но в другую БД.

Проблема конечно получится с производительностью. `inner join` без дополнительных условий нормально в таком случае не сделать, внешняя таблица будет копироваться локально.

Если производительность обращений к внешней таблице важнее строгой актуальности данных, то возможно сделать материализованное представление локально в базе и выполнять запросы к нему, можно добавить необходимые индексы. Затем периодически вызывать [`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW  CONCURRENTLY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) для обновления локальной копии таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли

Answer (score 3):

В postgresql нет встроенной поддержки запросов к нескольким базам данных по этому обычно используют либо одну базу данных с несколькими схемами внутри неё, либо разруливают ситуацию на стороне бекенда.

Однако есть модули, которые реализуют кросс-серверные запросы, например, [DBLink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) или [postgres-fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html).